# How can I solve this GIT issue in IntelliJ? My HEAD master* node is "go over" the remote origin/master

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control, ide, git-merge

I am working on a project using **IntelliJ** as IDE and **GIT** as repository.

I have the following problem:

[image]

As you can see it seems that my **HEAD master** node is "go over" the remote **origin/master** on my central repository.

Basically, as you can see in the right box, I have only added the **Config.java** file and I have modified the **pom.xml**.

Basically I think that I have to merge my local **HEAD master** and the remote **origin/master** nodes in this way:

- The **Config.java** file have to be added.
- The **pom.xml** file content have to be a merge of the content of my local **HEAD master** and the content remote **origin/master** (because me and my collegue both we have add something in this file).

How can I fix this situation from IntelliJ?

Comment: Have you merged your branches? look like you have a local master which is ot merged to the remote master

Comment: @CodeWizard eh...also I think that this could be the problem. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your comments here are the commands to follow in order to "fix" it:

Im writing the commands as they should be in the CLI but you can do it from your IDE as well.

```
# commit all your changes 
# (looks like they are already commited based upon your scresnshot)

# switch to the your local master branch
git checkout master

# now pull all your changes from the remote. This will result in a local merge
git pull origin master

# now fix any conflicts if there are any and push your changes back to your remote.
```

#### What does the above commands does?

You merge the remote changes into your local branch and than you push them back in order to update the remote with your changes.